# How do I display a list of data in a Spring JSP Page

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

How do I display a list of data in a Spring JSP Page.  Below you can see the code I have in my controller that is returning a list of messages but how do I create a list in the JSP page

```
public ModelAndView displayRequestPage(HttpSession session)
{
    Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    List<Message> myList = mService.listMessages();
    model.put("names", myList );
    return new ModelAndView("list", model);
}
```

Comment: Use JSTL and the `<c:foreach>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have placed `myList` in the model, it will be added to the request similar to adding any other attribute to the request.  You can reference the collection via JSP EL or scriptlets (although not preferred) from the JSP.  I would recommend using JSTL to iterate through the `List`.

**Using JSTL**

```
<c:forEach var="i" items="${names}">
   Name <c:out value="${i.fieldGoesHere}"/><p>
</c:forEach>
```