# java.util.List elements as HTML select option elements in JSP page - which way to use?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, jsp-tags

I use Spring framework, where I put different kind of values into ModelAndView-s, then I try to use them in my jsp pages. When I used a String value, it was easy, I put it into the ModelAndView:

```
mv.addObject("stringValue", "Hello Stackoverflow");
```

And I could read it on the jsp page (as far as I know, this kind of method is called JSP EL):

```
<input type="text" id="stringValue" name="stringValue" value="${stringValue}">
```

But when I tried to do the same with List elements:

```
mv.addObject("listElements", Arrays.asList("first", "second", "third", "fourth"));
```

I found difficult to use them in my JSP pages. I could handle them with JSP scriplets:

```
<select id="positionT" name="positionT" class="form-control">
        <%List<String> elements = (List<String>) request.getAttribute("listElements");
          for(String actElement : elements){
        %>
            <option value="<%=actElement %>"><%=actElement %></option>
        <%} %>
    </select>
```

But I read that using JSP scriplets is outdated. I also found the solution with [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16307814/how-do-i-display-a-list-of-data-in-a-spring-jsp-page) and the Spring Tag Libraries. I know a bit about Apache Velocity and Freemarker, so I know they would be a good solution. But is there a solution, where I don't have to use any kind of library, or any kind of template engine? And also avoid JSP scriplets? Like the way I used the simple String value. And also could someone tell me why JSP scriplets are outdated? Sorry for the dumb questions, the more I read about the different techniques the more I got confused about them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to list them in a select you should be able to do this:

```
<form:select path="listElements">
    <form:options items="${listElements}"></form:options>
</form:select>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but to use that I needed to add Spring's form tag library, and I'd like to use a solution that doesn't need any kind of library (and also avoid JSP scriplets). Is that possible? If it's not, I think I can accept your answer as a solution.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, or at least I haven't found a way. I use Freemarker and really like it, so if you want to try something like that out, I would recommend Freemarker.

Comment: I know a bit about Freemarker, because I have a little experience with Velocity and as far as I know, they are quiet similar. Maybe it's time for me to try it : - )
Thank you for your help!